# django POST returning Internal Server 500 error

Tags: python, ajax, django

I am trying to POST a request to a django view but it keeps returning `INTERNAL SERVER ERROR 500`.

My ajax post:

```
$.ajax({
    url : "/loginAction/",
    type : "POST",
    async : false,
    data : {action:'loginAction',
            email:email,
            password:password},

    success : function(response) {
        $.niftyNoty({
            type:"success",icon:"",title:"Login Successful. Redirecting....",container:"floating",timer:5000
        });
    },

    error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
        console.log(xhr.status + ": " + xhr.responseText);
        $.niftyNoty({
            type:"danger",icon:"",title:"Wrong Email OR Password",container:"floating",timer:5000
        });
    }
});
```

My django view:

```
def loginAction(request):
    print "Its workjing"
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'loginButton' in request.POST:
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        print email, password

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({}),content_type="application/json")
```

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
            url(r'^', views.loginPage, name='loginPage'),
            url(r'^loginAction/', views.loginAction, name='loginAction')
        ]
```

The ajax POST is not hitting the django view. It is not printing `Its working` in console. So its not returning the json response to ajax call. I also tried normal form POST but same result. I am using django 1.9.2. I cant figure out why this error?

It returns this error code:

```
Internal Server Error: /loginAction/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/manish/Desktop/admin_picknbox/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 158, in get_response
    % (callback.__module__, view_name))
ValueError: The view login_app.views.loginPage didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
```

EDIT:
ajax Header:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.ajaxSetup({
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems your urls are the problem because in the error appears that the `loginPage` view is called although you go to `/loginAction/`. So try to add `$` at the end of each regex as below:

```
urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.loginPage, name='loginPage'),
        url(r'^loginAction/$', views.loginAction, name='loginAction')
    ]
```

Because it appears that your first regex `r'^'` captures any url.

Answer (score 1):

Your view function doesn't take care of all cases, in case `if request.method == 'POST' and 'loginButton' in request.POST:` is `False`, you view function doesn't return anything, hence the error. Python function, if left without explicit `return` statement, would return `None`.

**Edit:**

If your `print` statement is not even executed, then you must have 403 response from django. You need to pass `csrf` token when you make ajax call to prevent attack from unknown person. Django would check `csrf` automatically, but you need to pass it as part of the data:

```
data : {action:'loginAction',
        email:email,
        password:password,
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
```

Also, you should check `"action" in request.POST` not `"loginAction" in request.POST`.

Comment: Ok then it should print `Its working` in console but it is not printing. It use to work perfectly in django 1.8.5 so i dont it has anything to do with POST catch

Comment: I have already passed csrftoken in ajax Header using this method:    See question

Comment: I created a js function which retrieves csrf token from cookie and then pass the token value to ajax header using the above function. I can see csrf token in POST in console.

Comment: If it's not printing `It's working`, what does your console say?

Comment: The console throes the error code i gave in question. this code works perfectly in django v1.8.5 . I recently upgraded django in a new virtualenv and this happens

Comment: That's really weird, maybe it's calling something else.

Comment: Ah, @doru got the answer before I find it out. You were calling a different method because your url has problems.

Answer (score 0):

i got this error one day but i latter realize that the page returning internal server error has the same name as the html page i wanted to return. i just changed the name of the html page i wanted t return and everything worked fine